# why can't i send email using php?

Tags: php, email

I have done the setting in `sendmail.ini` and `php.ini` so that I can send email by using gmail. The recipient is my hotmail. When I open my hotmail, nothing is received from my gmail. Can anyone help me with that? below is my php code:

```
<?php
    $to = 'kill_stealer90@hotmail.com';
    $subject = 'hello';
    $message = 'why i so pro';
    $headers = 'From:jackychickenchan@gmail.com';
    if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
        echo("<p>sent</p>");
    }else{
        echo("<p>failed</p>");
    }
?>
```

and here is my sendmail.ini setting

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=465

smtp_ssl=auto

auth_username=jackylonelyboy+gmail.com
auth_password=nemesis90
```

and here is my php.ini setting

```
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
; SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; smtp_port = 465
```

Comment: better go change the password on your email before someone steals it.. dude.. what's wrong with you.. putting your password on the internet!

Comment: don't worry,that email i just created for testing purpose,nothing inside

Comment: have you tried `smtp_ssl=ssl`

Comment: check the mail in spam!!

Comment: Word of advice, don't use PHP's `mail()`.

Comment: i have to use it because i am doing a project which require me sent an email to notify the user via php

Comment: It's unreliable. I used to have a small personal website where I got contact mail from people, and 1/5 times, I didn't get any mail. Not to mention, that every major mail provider will make your mail go to their SPAM folder.

Comment: Never experienced that.

Comment: @Vlad It works fine when the SMTP server, the server itself, and the mail script are set up properly. However, not everyone has control over the first two, or if they do, don't know how to set everything up correctly. The main drawback is the lack of errors, and the difficulty in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't uncomment your SMTP server. Take the semi-colons out of the SMTP and port lines in your php.ini.

Comment: still the same,nothing appear on my inbox....is there anything wrong with my configuration?

Comment: You may want to see if mail() is failing (returns false), and also check the error logs. The mail function works great when it works, it really stinks for trying to debug issues. You might want to try a package such as PHPMailer that would give you more information.

Comment: @user2740276 Did you restart Apache, PHP after making those changes?

Comment: @user2740276 Try putting a space in `$headers = 'From:jackychickenchan@gmail.com';` such as `$headers = 'From: jackychickenchan@gmail.com';` or try pre-defining a `$from="jackychickenchan@gmail.com";` variable then use `$headers = "From: $from" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $from" . "\r\n" .  "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();` instead of `$headers = 'From:jackychickenchan@gmail.com';` see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @user2740276 And what if you used `SMTP = ssl:smtp.gmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `jackylonelyboy@gmail.com` instead `jackylonelyboy+gmail.com` as user name for the authentication.

Comment: tried,doesn't work either...actually my friends have exactly same setting with me,his settings works great but mine doesn't work at all